# Accessing html form fields with an external application

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a command line tool to help expedite HTML form filling.  It uses a brute force approach in that it sends TAB keys to a window and writes info from a config file.  This is unstable so I want to refactor it to set form fields using javascript.

I've looked into writing a Firefox addon to do this.  I was able to hard-code each field id and write to it from a config file.  My issue is I need this functionality in IE.

Is there a way an external application (ie cmd line tool) can write to HTML fields using javascript?  I've tried recreating the entire html page with form fields filled in Java.  I then try to send this to the normal destination using an HTTP POST.  I ran into authentication issues because the forms require a log in.

My other idea is looking into web service tricks.  It may be unrelated, I have no idea.

Comment: If you are not into hard coding these yourself, you can search *formfillers*. They make these kind of jobs pretty easy. But if you want to build your own form filler, know that they are end user products.

Comment: I'd like to build my own.  This is a tool for a few colleagues.  Quality doesn't matter, it just needs to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like [Selenium?](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)
It will stop your reliance on hard coding everything as you have pretty much free reign over the DOM.

Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Looks great.  I'll try implementing today.  If it works I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: How did you find it? Were you able to implement what you wished?

Comment: It will not work.  I need a standalone application that does not require a third party server.  Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an CwebBrowser2 in your C++/C# application and use it as an HTML browser and get all the HTML programatically. You can then parse the HTML with a XML parses and call certain Javascript hooks.
The HTTP Post idea still seems best, if you have trouble with authenticating you just need to mimic that part as well or get the session ID (if a given session is enough for you).